# Something like "Power assert" in Scala similar to Groovy?

Tags: scala, groovy, assert, scalatest

I'm wondering if there is something that can give me results similar to Groovy's nice power assert statement.

```
> assert ["1", '2']*.size() == [2, 3]

Result: Assertion failed: 

assert ["1", '2']*.size() == [2, 3]
                   |      |
                   [1, 1] false
```

AFAIK there is no support for such thing neither in language, nor in 
`scalatest`, which I'm currently using.
But maybe someone can suggest some side library doing that? It's a pet project, so experimental and not well-supported libs are fine.

**EDIT:** I know about matchers (scalatest ones, or even plain-java hamcrest matchers). I find them verbose to write and that their output lacks details.

The example above shows intermediate computation steps, facilitating detection of errors. It shows you what's wrong with tested code with more details.

I expect, that introducing such behaviour will require having information about expression AST at runtime. But I suppose, that this information can be "baked" compile time with usage of macroses.

I.e. if we have expression `assert a + b == c` scala (or some macro extension I'm looking for) can rewrite it to something like:

```
if (!(a + b == c)) {
  // detailed message is
  // compute a
  // compute b
  // compute a + b
  // compute c
  // compute a + b == c
  // Make it pretty.

  throw new AssertionFailedException(prettyDetailedMessage)
}
```

So I'm looking if it's already implemented, and if yes - where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ScalaTest, you can use DiagrammedAssertions.
See http://www.scalatest.org/release_notes/2.2.0#diagrammedAssertions

This is based on Expecty which is a macro-based implementation of Spock's power assertions. See https://github.com/pniederw/expecty

Comment: Awesome! That's what I've been looking. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Specs2 matchers do a good job with error messages:

```
class Specs2Specification extends Specification {
  "specs2 assertion" should {
    "fail" in {
      List("1", "2").map(_.length) must_=== List(2, 3)
    }  
  }
}
```

run output:

```
[info] Specs2Specification
[info]
[info] specs2 assertion should
[error]   x fail
[error]    List(1, 1) is not equal to List(2, 3) 
[info]
[error] Added (2)
[error] 1
[error] 1
[info]
[error] Missing (2)
[error] 2
[error] 3
```

or

```
List("1", "2").map(_.length) must contain(exactly(2, 3)).inOrder
```

which produces

```
[error]   x fail
[error]    the values 2, 3 are not in order
```

There are [lots of them](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html) and you can create custom ones.

Answer (score 0):

Your `groovy` code snippet is literally translated to the following `scala` code (given that you're already using `scalatest`):

```
assert((List("1", "2") map (_.length)) === List(2, 3))
```

It produces the following error message:

```
*** FAILED ***
List(1, 1) did not equal List(1, 3)
```

Comment: The point is, that Groovy automatically show intermediate computation steps in readable format. I know about scala matchers, but you should agree, that code above is more readable and produces more detailed exceptions. 
I'll improve my question to emphasize that fact.